# Error Code: 38191, Invalid HTTP header when I visit the url I built using urlBuilder as shown below

Tags: java, android, amadeus

I'm currently working on an Android project that involves making HTTP requests to the Amadeus Flight Offers API. I've encountered an issue with the API request, and I'm hoping to get some guidance on how to resolve it.

The problem I'm facing is related to the HTTP 401 (Unauthorized) error that I'm receiving when trying to access the API. The error message specifically states that the "Authorization" header is missing or in an invalid format. I've double-checked my code, and it seems like I'm setting the header correctly. However, I might be missing something or mis-configuring it unintentionally.

Here's a breakdown of my code where  I construct the base URL for the API:

```
HttpUrl baseHttpUrl = HttpUrl.parse("https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers");

        if (baseHttpUrl != null) {
            HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = baseHttpUrl.newBuilder();
            urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("originLocationCode", origin);
            urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("destinationLocationCode", destination);
            urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("departureDate", fromDate);
            urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("returnDate", toDate); // If round-trip search
            Log.d("SearchActivity", "URL: " + urlBuilder.build());
```

**To be more specific, the URL I get from the log redirects me to a page saying** -

> errors
> 0
> code    38191
> title   "Invalid HTTP header"
> detail  "Missing or invalid format for mandatory Authorization header"
> status  401

I feel I am making an error somewhere here, I attempt to perform the GET request using the following method -

```
public String performGetRequest(String endpoint, HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder) throws IOException {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(BASE_URL + endpoint)
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + API_KEY)
                .url(urlBuilder.build())
                .build();

        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                return response.body().string();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the request builder you are calling the `url()` method tow times, that's the main cause of your problem.
I am not sure of your use case but I think you will only need the second call `url(urlBuilder.build())` as this will contain the `baseUrl+endpoint+parameters` .

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your time and response. Right, I have fixed it. I have been reading the authentication documentation's Authorization Guide, and I think I am mistakenly passing the API KEY instead of the access_token in the header of performGetRequest. However, I didn't really understand how to get an access token. The documentary says " you can generate an access token by sending a POST request to the authorization server:
https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token". This token should be passed in the header. However, I am not sure how to do this.